# How can I search all the remote repos from GIT server

Tags: git

I am working to search all the occurrence of a keyword in git remote repos on git server .. but I am not sure about all the remote repo name..

Is there a git command to search/list all the git repo on a particular git server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a git command to search/list all the git repo on a particular git server

**You cant.**

Git does not store reference who cloned the repository.